# Evaluating part(s) of a function which outputs another function

Tags: evaluation, pure-function

I would like to define a function `f(n)` which outputs another function as follows:

```
f[n_] := PolynomialRemainder[#,ChebyshevT[n,x],x]&
```

However, I would like the `ChebyshevT[n,x]` *part* of the function to be *evaluated* when `f` is called, so that for instance when `f(2)` is evaluated I get `PolynomialRemainder[#,-1+2x^2,x]&` instead of `PolynomialRemainder[#,ChebyshevT[2,x],x]&`.

How do I do that? If I wrap the function body in an `Evaluate` as follows:

```
f[n_] := Evaluate[PolynomialRemainder[#,ChebyshevT[n,x],x]]&
```

then the whole definition gets evaluated, and the input `#` is assumed to be free of `x`, resulting in `f[2] = #&`.

Comment: Use `With[{poly = Chebyshev[n, x]}, ...`

Comment: @Kuba thanks, that works! Please enter it as an answer then I will accept it.